# How to list Docker host volumes?

Tags: docker, volume

When I run `docker volume ls` this command shows my normal volumes but not host volumes.

How can I ls that type of volumes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of [Go template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) formatting, the [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/) can be pulled from [`docker inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/)

```
docker inspect --format \
  '{{range .Mounts}}{{if eq .Type "bind"}}{{$.Id}} {{.Source}}:{{.Destination}}{{end}}{{end}}' \
  $(docker ps -aq) \
  | grep '.'
```

I'm not sure how to remove the blank lines in Go, hence the `grep`. I think it might be `docker inspect` adding those.

Comment: The blank lines are from any container that you inspect without any host mounts. Every template outputs at least one line, and every container runs the template again.